# get a javascript object as a link

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help; i want the name obtained from the json array to be a link; that is, once I get the name I click on it to be directed to a page (for example, it is assumed [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)).
To do this I used the following line:

*document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "+myObj["name"]+";*

but I get nothing. Can anyone help me please?

```js
const myJSON = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>+myObj["
name "]+</a>";
```

```html
<h2>Access a JavaScript Object</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You've messed with the quoting of the HTML string. It should be `..." + myObj.name + "</a>"`.

Comment: it doesn't work the same

Comment: Please [tell me more about it](https://jsfiddle.net/r5fh8uxv/).

Comment: ok perfect, one little thing was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>"+myObj['name']+"</a>";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<a href='http://www.google.com'>${myObj["name"]}</a>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Access a JavaScript Object</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const myJSON = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `<a href='http://www.google.com'>${myObj["name"]}</a>`;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```